# BASH / Command Line number of bytes

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In this directory when I run

```
ls -l
```

it prints the following output:

-rw------- 1 csundl dcsugrad    **0** Dec  5 13:51 file3 
drwx------ 2 csundl dcsugrad **4096** Dec  5 13:51 Photos 
drwx------ 2 csundl dcsugrad **4096** Dec  5 13:51 Pron 
drwx------ 2 csunfi dcsugrad **4096** Dec  5 13:51 Spreadsheets 
drwx------ 3 csundl dcsugrad **4096** Dec  5 15:12 Stuff 
-rwx------ 1 csundl dcsugrad  **149** Dec  5 15:08 untitled.sh

The bolded values are the byte sizes (?).

However when I run:

```
ls -l | wc -c
```

The total byte size comes up as 340. Why is this?

Thanks.

Comment: This does not apply to this question, but even if a question is closed, you should not delete it in general, if it has a non-negative score.

Comment: I really like how you did not filter your `ls -l` output ;-)

Comment: @RedX what? "Pron" is just a progressive cron program. What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` command displays size of the file

but this command:

```
ls -l | wc -c
```

counts number of characters in the output of `ls` command.

**To count total size of files in a directory use `du` command:**

```
du -hs mydir
```

Comment: I just realised, durrrr. Thanks!

What would be a good route for calculating the total size, in bytes, of a directories files USING LS

Comment: we have to use ls for this exercise.

Comment: Parsing `ls` command for this calculation is not a good idea. I will get lots of hate comments if I post a script to sum up file sizes from `ls`'s output :)

Comment: "you will need to parse the output of an ls in order to find the size of each file in order to calculate the total space usage"

Not even a hint :P

Comment: Ok, you can use this script: `ls -l | awk '{s+=$5} END {print s}'` to get the sum of file sizes.

Comment: @Lecaille Hmm, your teacher is incorrectly telling you *you will need to parse the output of an ls*, but he/she is not actually requiring you to do it, based on that quote. Please read the `du` manpage, and [this treatise on why you should never parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Then, do the assignment both ways for the best education. You'll be smarter than your teacher very shortly.